# How can I make www-data's cronjobs to be executed?

Tags: shell, cron

I do have a server managed with Django which has Python-Crontab installed on it. Due to Django being executed by www-data user, all the Python-Crontab jobs I'm saving are being written on www-data's crontab table, but those any rule on that table are not executed.

Of course, cron service is running and all jobs on root's table are running fine, but none of the www-data's. I've tried:

- setting it into the crontab group
- giving it permission over `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/www-data`
- write simple rules as: `* * * * date >> /var/log/cron.log`

Any clue on what should I try?

Comment: do you have an /etc/cron.allow file?  did you check inside /etc/cron.deny

Comment: also, trying to write to a root owned file (`/var/log/cron.log`)  is a bad idea, I usually do `> /tmp/mycron.$$` for testing cron

Comment: Writing on tmp works, so it seems like a path permissions problem. Thanks!